# Can I run new Date() as an argument to a $scope.function while using ng-init?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function called populateTasks that requires two arguments: a new Date() and the key to an angularfire object. Is it possible to run from the view?

```
ng-init="populateTasks(new Date(), key)
```

The controller has $scope.populateTasks as a function. "key" is available because I'm running through another object using ng-repeat.

Comment: No it is not. The Angular parser does not parse date expressions.

Comment: Is there some other way to achieve the desired result? I need to uniquely populate an ng-repeat with different data based on the key of the user. Can I generate a new Date() some other way?

Comment: I posted an answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: Instead of doing a `new Date()` why don't you do it in the populateTasks method, and just reduce it to `populateTasks(key)`. It is not that the `The Angular parser does not parse date expressions`, it is because Date constructor is a part of window/global object, and it is not exposed as a part of `$scope`. All binding expressions in angular are evaluated against the `$scope` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angular parser will not parse "new" expressions.  There is a way around this though.  Just define a Date() function on your scope that returns a new Date:

Controller

```
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.Date = function() {
        return new Date();
    };
    $scope.populateTasks = function(date) {
       alert(date);
    };
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl" ng-init="populateTasks(Date())">
</div>
```